# How to add and remove event in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have an image that has an InnerHTML for "a href" tag define in the .cs file as shown below.

```
HtmlGenericControl _divToolTipContainer = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
_divToolTipContainer.InnerHtml = "<a href=\"javascript:__doPostBack('" + btnItemThumbnail.ClientID.Replace("_", "$") + "','')\">" +
                              <img src='" + string.Format("ItemPreview.axd/{0}/width-250/height-328/", item.ID.ToString()) + "'></a>;
```

Now what I want is to have this "a href" event "remove" say if condition is (false) else "add" the event again by using jQuery. Sample code is shown below.

```
var objectDiv = document.getElementById(oElementId);    // get the object id 

If (false){ // condition here
    remove the event of the a href tag..
    jquery code must be added here..
}else{
    add the event again of the a href tag..
    jQuery code must be added here..
}
```

How to do this?

Thanks

Jason

Answer (score 1):

You may as well use jQuery to select the element by the ID as well, so

```
(function($) {

    var objectDiv = $("#"+oElementId);    // get the object id 

    if(false)
    { // condition here
        objectDiv.removeAttr("href"); 
    }
    else
    {
         objectDiv.attr("href", "javascript:__doPostBack('" + btnItemThumbnail.ClientID.Replace("_", "$") + "','')");
    } 

})(jQuery);
```

Edit: You may have to wrap your code in the (function($) to make sure your code is using the $ for jQuery

Comment: Try my above code now. (Note: you will have to wrap everything that is to be used in the `if else` statement inside of that)

Comment: Still now working,  I can still click the image and it will go to the a href location being provided...

Comment: If it was just going to the "add your event here" or whatever I had put there before, then the code must be working, but I hadn't put your javascript code in there, but i have now edited my answer with that code there.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (false) {
    $('#oElementId').off('click', function() {});
} else {
    $('#oElementId').on('click', function() {});
}
```